# See what page is open in Google Chrome

Tags: java

I was wondering if it was possible to find out the URL of the page that is open in a browser, such as Google Chrome.

I was thinking the best way would be to make a Chrome extension that would log the current URL of whatever tab was open in a file, then the Java application would just have to read the file, but is there a way to do this without the extension?

I found [Check what the current URL is in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42283538/check-what-the-current-url-is-in-browser), but I was not sure if this was the same question, as the OP of that question was looking to complete it using the Selenium libraries, but still was not given an answer.

Is the extension the best way, or can Java do this without it?

Thanks.

EDIT: By the looks of things, Chrome extensions can't save files anyway, so I'm really not sure if this is possible.

Comment: This question is probably too broad. Have you already tried anything?

Comment: @YassinHajaj I hate to say it, but no. I can't think of anything to get me even close to what I am trying to do.

Comment: No problem but I think it would be a nice thing to begin from there, trying to solve the problem on your own then come and ask questions if you're really stuck. `Is the extension the best way...` will also bring primarly-opinion based answers which is not really the goal of SO. Good luck with it anyway, hope you find something clearing the path a little bit